# Convert regular Postgres Database into a spatial database

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I have looked everywhere but most tutorials are for creating a spatial database. Is it possible to convert a regular Postgresql db into a spatial one?

I will be using this for GeoDjango.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does [this](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db) help?  Quoting from the Postgres manual:

> Now load the PostGIS object and function definitions into your
>   database by loading the postgis.sql definitions file (located in
>   [prefix]/share/contrib as specified during the configuration step).
>
> ```
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -f postgis.sql
> ```
>
> For a complete set of EPSG coordinate system definition identifiers,
>   you can also load the spatial_ref_sys.sql definitions file and
>   populate the spatial_ref_sys table. This will permit you to perform
>   ST_Transform() operations on geometries.
>
> ```
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
> ```
>
> If you wish to add comments to the PostGIS functions, the final step
>   is to load the postgis_comments.sql into your spatial database. The
>   comments can be viewed by simply typing \dd [function_name] from a
>   psql terminal window.
>
> ```
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -f postgis_comments.sql
> ```

Answer (score 4):

(Low reputation -- this deserves to a be a comment instead of an answer)

For those arriving from Google, the top-rated answer applies to PostGres versions lower than 9.1.  For 9.1+, all you need is this (from [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions)):

> The core postgis extension installs PostGIS geometry, geography, raster, spatial_ref_sys and all the functions and comments with a simple:
>
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
>   command.
>
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
>
> Topology is packaged as a separate extension and installable with command:
>
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
>
> If you plan to restore an old backup from prior versions in this new db, run:
>
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -f legacy.sql
>
> You can later run uninstall_legacy.sql to get rid of the deprecated functions after you are done with restoring and cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

For the database itself, just install PostGIS and you have a spatial database.

If you want to convert your actual data, that obviously depends on what your data is. But since it's all accessible over SQL, it can certainly be done.